# How can I install Alpine Apache Benchmark?

Tags: alpine-linux, apachebench

When I run `apk add --update ab` there's an error:

```
bash-4.3# apk add --update ab
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  ab (missing):
    required by: world[ab]
bash-4.3# apk add ab
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  ab (missing):
    required by: world[ab]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for the `apache2-utils` package:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.8/main/x86_64/apache2-utils

It includes `ab` along with several other utilities.
See package contents [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=v3.8&name=apache2-utils&arch=x86_64&repo=main).